# How to write the T(n) for this function?

Tags: java, algorithm

I stumbled upon this question on the Python interactive site and I was wondering how to calculate the duration of this step by step in Java so that I can show it's time efficiency.

```
int i = n;
while (i > 0)
{
    int k = 2 + 2;
    i = i / 2;
}
```

Comment: what is `k` doing here?

Comment: You could put that into a function, call that function 100 000 times and using `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the method is called sum up the time spent on 100 000 times, and then repeat for a wide range of input values. Then you can export it to a .csv file (either using some sort of API or just `print` the results to the console) and graph it in Excel or some sort of spreadsheet software.

Comment: I asked for it to be shown step by step. How did you arrive at T(log2(n)) ?? Can you show me line by line what that line addes to the Time equation?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza actually, you provided complexity in O notation. T(n) denotes exact number of steps. BTW, knowing number of steps, it is easy to resolve T(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose input n = i = 2<sup>x</sup>.

Every step divides i by 2: so i = 2<sup>x</sup> becomes 2<sup>x-1</sup>.

That is repeated until 0, i. e. 2<sup>-1</sup>. (*)

So number of steps = x ~ log<sub>2</sub>n

---

*actually, 2<sup>-1</sup> = 1/2, but in terms of integer division it would be the last step where 2<sup>0</sup> = 1 is divided by 2, resuling 0.